# Change button content depending on button clicked

Tags: c#

I'm working on a tic tac toe game for an assignment, and the way I want to make the game doesn't seem possible. I think other people have asked this question, but all of the code I've seen in any answers online is more advanced (or seems that way) than what I am trying to do.

Currently, I am using 1 click event for all 9 of my buttons. When player 1 plays, it becomes player 2's turn.

Because I'm using the same click event for all the buttons, I can't figure out how to make the content of each button change to "X" or "O" depending on who's turn it is.

If I were doing 9 different click events, I know how to do it, but the point of this assignment is to use methods for simplicity and it is driving me crazy.

My initial feeling is there should be a "this.Content = "X";" option or something.

Here is the code I have so far (minus a few methods already working. There are asterisks around the lines of code I want to work, but don't know what to do to get them working.):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    bool turn;
    string playerX;
    string playerO;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void IsTurn ()
    {
        if (turn==true)
        {
            textBlockGameInfo.Text = "It is " + playerO + "'s turn";
            **button_Click.Content = "O";**
            turn = false;
        }
        else if (turn==false)
        {
            textBlockGameInfo.Text = "It is " + playerX + "'s turn";
            **button_Click.Content = "X";**
            turn = true;
        }
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsTurn();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: why don't you just change the button's text, or add an image to it?

Comment: Are trying to do this - ((Button)sender).Text = turn ? "O" : "X";

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely cast the sender received in the method as a `Button`. The sender in the `button_Click` method will be the button on which a player actually clicked.

Once casted as a button, you could then set its content according to the turn. Your turn method could be returning the character to assign. Something a bit like this would work:

```
var button = sender as Button;
if (button == null) return;

button.Content = IsTurn();
```

Comment: What exactly does "sender as Button;" mean/do? I am brand new to this stuff and it is definitely showing :/   The last line you wrote, "button.Content = IsTurn();" references my IsTurn method. How is referencing that going to change the content of the button, when I don't know what to put in the method itself to set the content?

Comment: The `sender as button` part will cast the `object` to a `Button`. You will then have access to properties of the button. For the usage of your `IsTurn()` method, I suggest you reformat it to return the wanted string instead of `void`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the Button.Text property.

When player 1 clicks the button, you're gonna want to do

```
button.Text = "O";
```

and when player 2 clicks the button:

```
button.Text = "X";
```

Comment: @KOTIX Yes they do. I was assuming this was a WinForms application. If it is, then there is a text property, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @GeMaths If it's not then you can use Content

Answer (score 0):

Trying to follow @KOTIX 's advice, I got my game working, but I'm still kind of confused as to how the button situation worked itself out. I think I just need to go back and review some things.

Here's my final code for the whole tic tac toe game. Look at the last 2 methods to see how the button_click was handled and used.

I also think there has got to be a better way to handle figuring out the winner, but that's another question for another time :)

Hopefully this can help another person out there.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TicTacToe
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        Random random = new Random();

        int firstPlayer = 0;
        bool turn;
        bool winner = true;
        string playerX;
        string playerO;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ResetBoard ()
        {
            //Clear Xs & Os:
            buttonTopLeft.Content = "";
            buttonMiddleTop.Content = "";
            buttonTopRight.Content = "";

            buttonMiddleLeft.Content = "";
            buttonMiddle.Content = "";
            buttonMiddleRight.Content = "";

            buttonLowerLeft.Content = "";
            buttonMiddleBottom.Content = "";
            buttonBottomRight.Content = "";

            //make board playable
            winner = false;

            //reset background colors
            buttonTopLeft.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            buttonMiddleTop.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            buttonTopRight.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            buttonMiddleLeft.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            buttonMiddle.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            buttonMiddleRight.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            buttonLowerLeft.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            buttonMiddleBottom.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            buttonBottomRight.Background = Brushes.LightGray;

        }

        private void ChooseFirstPlayer ()
        {
            if (textBoxPlayerO.Text == "Audra")
            {
                turn = false;
                playerX = textBoxPlayerX.Text;
                playerO = textBoxPlayerO.Text;
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerO + " goes first";
            }
            else if (textBoxPlayerX.Text == "Audra")
            {
                turn = true;
                playerX = textBoxPlayerX.Text;
                playerO = textBoxPlayerO.Text;
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerX + " goes first";
            }
            else
            {
                firstPlayer = random.Next(1, 3);

                if (textBoxPlayerO.Text == "" || textBoxPlayerX.Text == "")
                {
                    textBlockGameInfo.Text = "Please enter both player's names";
                }
                else
                {

                    if (firstPlayer == 1)
                    {
                        turn = true;
                        playerX = textBoxPlayerX.Text;
                        playerO = textBoxPlayerO.Text;
                        textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerX + " goes first";
                    }
                    else if (firstPlayer == 2)
                    {
                        turn = false;
                        playerX = textBoxPlayerX.Text;
                        playerO = textBoxPlayerO.Text;
                        textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerO + " goes first";
                    }
                }
            }

            }

        private void buttonStartGame_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ResetBoard();
            ChooseFirstPlayer();
        }

        private void IsNoWinner ()
        {
            if (buttonTopLeft.Content != "" && buttonMiddleTop.Content != "" && buttonTopRight.Content != "" &&
                buttonMiddleLeft.Content != "" && buttonMiddle.Content != "" && buttonMiddleRight.Content != "" &&
                buttonLowerLeft.Content != "" && buttonMiddleBottom.Content != "" && buttonBottomRight.Content != "" && winner == false)
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = "It's a draw!";
            }
        }

        private void IsXWinner ()
        {
            if (buttonTopLeft.Content == "X" && buttonMiddleTop.Content == "X" && buttonTopRight.Content == "X")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerX + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonTopLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddleTop.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonTopRight.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
            else if (buttonMiddleLeft.Content == "X" && buttonMiddle.Content == "X" && buttonMiddleRight.Content =="X")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerX + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
            }
            else if (buttonLowerLeft.Content == "X" && buttonMiddleBottom.Content == "X" && buttonBottomRight.Content == "X")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerX + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonMiddleLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddle.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddleRight.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
            else if (buttonTopLeft.Content == "X" && buttonMiddleLeft.Content == "X" && buttonLowerLeft.Content == "X")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerX + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonTopLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddleLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonLowerLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
            else  if (buttonMiddleTop.Content == "X" && buttonMiddle.Content == "X" && buttonMiddleBottom.Content == "X")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerX + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonMiddleTop.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddle.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddleBottom.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
            else if (buttonLowerLeft.Content == "X" && buttonMiddleBottom.Content == "X" && buttonBottomRight.Content == "X")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerX + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonLowerLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddleBottom.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonBottomRight.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
            else if (buttonTopLeft.Content == "X" && buttonMiddle.Content == "X" && buttonBottomRight.Content == "X")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerX + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonTopLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddle.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonBottomRight.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
            else if (buttonTopRight.Content == "X" && buttonMiddle.Content == "X" && buttonLowerLeft.Content == "X")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerX + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonTopRight.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddle.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonLowerLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }


        }

        private void IsOWinner()
        {
            if (buttonTopLeft.Content == "O" && buttonMiddleTop.Content == "O" && buttonTopRight.Content == "O")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerO + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonTopLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddleTop.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonTopRight.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
            else if (buttonMiddleLeft.Content == "O" && buttonMiddle.Content == "O" && buttonMiddleRight.Content == "O")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerO + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonMiddleLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddle.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddleRight.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
            else if (buttonLowerLeft.Content == "O" && buttonMiddleBottom.Content == "O" && buttonBottomRight.Content == "O")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerO + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
            }
            else if (buttonTopLeft.Content == "O" && buttonMiddleLeft.Content == "O" && buttonLowerLeft.Content == "O")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerO + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonTopLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddleLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonLowerLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
            else if (buttonMiddleTop.Content == "O" && buttonMiddle.Content == "O" && buttonMiddleBottom.Content == "O")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerO + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonMiddleTop.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddle.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddleBottom.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
            else if (buttonLowerLeft.Content == "O" && buttonMiddleBottom.Content == "O" && buttonBottomRight.Content == "O")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerO + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonLowerLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddleBottom.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonBottomRight.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
            else if (buttonTopLeft.Content == "O" && buttonMiddle.Content == "O" && buttonBottomRight.Content == "O")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerO + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonTopLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddle.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonBottomRight.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
            else if (buttonTopRight.Content == "O" && buttonMiddle.Content == "O" && buttonLowerLeft.Content == "O")
            {
                textBlockGameInfo.Text = playerO + " is the winner!";
                winner = true;
                buttonTopRight.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonMiddle.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
                buttonLowerLeft.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
            }
        }

        private void PlayButton(Button buttonClicked)
        {
            if (buttonClicked.Content == "")
            {
                if (turn == true)
                {
                    textBlockGameInfo.Text = "It is " + playerO + "'s turn";
                    buttonClicked.Content = "X";
                    turn = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    textBlockGameInfo.Text = "It is " + playerX + "'s turn";
                    buttonClicked.Content = "O";
                    turn = true;
                }
            }

        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (winner != true)
            {
                var button = sender as Button;

                PlayButton(button);
                IsXWinner();
                IsOWinner();
                IsNoWinner();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If my answer helped you get there, I suggest you mark it as the answer. Thanks !